# mysql, innodb settings for faster execution of query

Tags: mysql

I have 4 large table and im trying to execute sql query on it. The query is taking much time to execute so , i want to reduce the execution time for better performance and i'm struggling with this so i need help

i'm using mysql 5.7.8 in linux os, 12 GB RAM

*This is my.cnf config *
my.cnf file

```
 [mysqld]    
innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G     
innodb_log_buffer_size=2G    
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16    
innodb_thread_concurrency=0    
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0    
sync_binlog=0    
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT    
skip_name_resolve    
innodb_io_capacity=1000    
innodb_io_capacity_max=3000    
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=ON    
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=ON    
query_cache_type = 1    
query_cache_size = 256M    
innodb_read_io_threads=8    
innodb_write_io_threads=4
```

Comment: How many cpu cores do you have? Provide the results for query `SHOW STATUS`, this query returns server status information.

Comment: Try to optimize the queries prior to optimize the server. There is no magic configuration, every my.cnf depends on the specifics of the server load, queries, concurrent users, etc...

Comment: @Max P show status file link    https://www.dropbox.com/s/6dyjhlztt7jprh6/show_status?dl=0

Comment: What's the query? What are the tables? Do you use joins, ordering, grouping ? Do you use indexes? Basic details are missing.

Comment: Query: SELECT `Quarter`, `ClaimType`,`Year`, SUM(`Units`) AS `Units`, SUM(`Amount`) AS `Amount` FROM `acttabs` AS `acttab` WHERE `acttab`.`isCancel` = 1 AND `acttab`.`User` = 'Sapna' GROUP BY `Quarter`, `Year`,`ClaimType`;

Comment: Seems that you restarted server before getting status vars, uptime is 2 minutes. Run this command after several hours of server working

Comment: yeah i restarted the server...i will update this after some time@Max P

Comment: i am not using indexes @ Mr. Girgitt

Comment: @Max P: show status link- https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8ayxljbyan9w8g/show_status1?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with status vars, very low activity.
Try to add composite index `(isCancel, User)`.
If the query will remain slow, than delete this index and try to add new one `(isCancel, User, Quarter, Year, ClaimType, Units, Amount)` that will allow to get all data from index for this query.